# JavaScript Injection - Manipulate Objects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, code-injection

I want to inject JavaScript to a website **locally** via address bar.
The purpose is to make some modifications of the website **only for me**.

What is the correct way to find and then **manipulate objects / variables**? Especially when the JS is obfuscated.

Say, I know for sure there has to be an instance of a certain class which has a certain method.
F12 both on Chrome and on FF did not help me too much but maybe I am doing something wrong.

To be more precise, I will give a real problem.
[This website](http://lichess.org/) is an open source chess server.
It uses an open source library to represent a board ([github](https://github.com/ornicar/chessground)).
I know for sure that there has to be a `move()` method.

Now the question is simple: how do I find this instance and calling `move()` in order to programmatically move pieces?

Comment: You can try to de-obfuscate the code. Even then you might not have access to the functions from global scope.

Comment: Use dev tools (Menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools) to manipulate the current page.  Typing `window.` in the Console will show you everything in the page global state in a context menu or you could `console.log(window)`

Comment: @dtanders I did this in the first place. There are too many things and hell knows which of them is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Hodrobond Is it a language / interpreter limitation? I spent many hours trying to do it and no success. If it is a limitation could you refer me to the relevant docs please?

Comment: I think you want `lichess.ab.move`.  I found that by finding lichess.site.min.js in the Sources panel, clicking { } to pretty print it and scrolling past all the library stuff to the bootstrap code at the bottom.

Comment: @dtanders unfortunately it does not work...

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily possible. After looking at the code, specifically `lichess.round.min.js` (I recommend doing a search for `this.apiMove`), it appears that it's locked behind es6 modules and isn't publicly exported. Maybe try creating a content script (in a chrome extension) that replaces the script with a modified version that does export the module globally.